# Are there competitors to Jeppesen making Electronic Flight Folders?

Tags: flight-planning

Jeppesen has made Electronic Flight Folders and seems to be a pioneer in that. Do they have any competitors for that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about exactly what you mean by an EFF? In the GA world at least there are many tools available for flight planning and tracking - usually on a tablet - but I'm not sure if that's what you really mean.

Answer (score 1):

For the UK NATS makes most of the charts which I frequently use for flight stimulation. I believe that for charts especially the Aerodrome charts are much better than the style of charts Jeppesen produce. The only downside is that the charts aren't compiled in the way that charts on Jeppesen are and must be compiled. But for outside the UK the best charts in my opinion are Jeppesen.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, yes, there is a company called Flightman which also makes EFFs. I don't see any other companies listed that make them.